# C# WPF Progress bar not fully updating with background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I am working on a program that gets the MD5 hash signature from files that the user has selected then run it through a text file of well-known virus md5 and checks for a match. What I came to realize is that some files take a bit of time to convert. I have attempted to get a progress bar to work but have an issue where I only get it to update when it has finished and it ignores my other report progress. Any help appreciated

Here is the code for the Progress bar:

```
private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => 
    {
        BackgroundWorker scanner = new BackgroundWorker();
        scanner.RunWorkerCompleted += scanner_RunScannerCompleted;
        scanner.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        scanner.DoWork += scanner_Scan;
        scanner.ProgressChanged += scanner_ProgressChanged;
        scanner.RunWorkerAsync();
    }));
}

private void scanner_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => 
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }));
}

private void scanner_Scan(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        var scanner = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        scanner.ReportProgress(0);
        scanner.ReportProgress(10);
        scanner.ReportProgress(20);

        getMD5(tbFilePath.Text);

        scanner.ReportProgress(80);

        checkSignatures();
        scanner.ReportProgress(100);
    }));
}

private void scanner_RunScannerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Scan Complete");
        progressBar.Value = 0;
    }));
}
```

I have already tried to add the "this.Dispatcher.Invoke" as I have already seen from other pages that this should fix the issue but hasn't for me.

Comment: Did you ever try it without the `this.Dispatcher.Invoke`?

Comment: I would recommend to forget about the background worker and instead run a [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) passing it an `IProgress<int>` for progress reporting.

Comment: You're creating a new thread (BackgroundWorker), but then calling this.Dispatcher.Invoke to do the actual work on the GUI thread. GUI thread is now starved, that's why you're not seeing it update until your worker thread is done. Fadzii is correct...BackgroundWorker has been obsolete for about 15 years now, you should be using [asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Isn't your progress a double (between 0.0 and 1.0)?